# Chrome Extension "Stats" broken since update?

Tags: chrome-web-store

I recently updated a Chrome extension I have, and since the update my Stats has shown 0s for both views and installs. Here's what the chart looks like:

[image: Stats chart]

Any idea why this might be happening? From an Incognito window I can still find my extension in the Chrome store.

For those curious, the extension is called "Prioritab"

Answer (score 0):

Did you by any chance change the Extension name with the update? I'm noticing the same behaviour with my app and I changed the app name with the latest update.

Can't think of what else might have caused it...